# Flutter Insert data into the database sqflite

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, sqflite

I need to `insert` the `data` one at a time and add it to the end of the `string`, but what happens is that the way I'm doing is overwriting the `data`

```
 for (var i = 0; i< isChecked.length; i++) {
  receipt.ingredientsReceipt = isChecked[i]; //receipt is table name, ingredientsReceipt is column name
  print(isChecked[i]);// isChecked is my list containing [ING 1, ING 2, ING 3]
 }
```

Output:

```
I/flutter ( 5360): ING 1
I/flutter ( 5360): ING 2
I/flutter ( 5360): ING 3
```

This is my `SQL`:

```
CREATE TABLE receipt(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, nameReceipt TEXT, descReceipt TEXT, ingredientsReceipt TEXT)
```

Output `SQL`:

```
{id: null, nameReceipt: TEST, descReceipt: TEST, ingredientsReceipt: ING 3}
```

I need it to be like this:

```
{id: 1, nameReceipt: TEST, descReceipt: TEST, ingredientsReceipt: ING 1, ING 2, ING 3}
```

Comment: You should rework your database schema with 3 tables : `receipts`, `ingredients` and `receipt_ingredient`. The last one will link a receipt to several ingredients (2 columns : receipt_fk and ingredient_fk) so for 1 receipt you will have all ids to ingredients. It's better than concatenat a list.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my comment, use 3 tables  :

**RECEIPTS**

| id | nameReceipt | descReceipt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | desc1 |
| 2 | name2 | desc2 |

**INGREDIENTS**

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ingr1 |
| 2 | ingr2 |
| 3 | ingr3 |
| 4 | ingr4 |

**RECEIPT_INGREDIENT**

| id | receipt_fk | ingredient_fk |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 4 |

So when you want to get a receipt, you'll have to write a query to select data from receipt, join with receipt_ingredient (where receipt.id = receipt_ingredient.receipt_fk), join with ingredient (where receipt_ingredient.ingredeint_fk = ingredient.id).

*Ex.* get receipt id = 1 =>

| id | nameReceipt | descReceipt | receipt_fk | ingredient_fk | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | desc1 | 1 | 1 | ingr1 |
| 1 | name1 | desc1 | 1 | 2 | ingr2 |
| 1 | name1 | desc1 | 1 | 3 | ingr3 |